# How to compare symbols between 2 multifield-variable in CLIPS

Tags: clips

The problem is to compare between two multifield-variable of type SYMBOL.
Here an example of the code I try to develop.

```
CLIPS>(defrule r       
=>
(printout t "Input A: ")
(bind $?A (explode$ (readline)))

(printout t "Input B: ")
(bind $?B (explode$ (readline)))

(if (member$ $?A $?B) then (printout t " Something ..." crlf)))
CLIPS> (run)
Input A: 1 2 3 4 5
Input B: 7 3 2 1 6
CLIPS>
```

I want to compare each argument (or value) of $?A with each argument of $?B and if at least one argument of both is in the $?A or $?B, the if test becomes TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function to test for the intersection of two multifield values:

```
CLIPS> 
(deffunction intersectionp (?m1 ?m2)
   (foreach ?i1 ?m1
      (foreach ?i2 ?m2
         (if (eq ?i1 ?i2)
            then (return TRUE))))
   (return FALSE))
CLIPS> 
(defrule r       
   =>
   (printout t "Input A: ")
   (bind ?A (explode$ (readline)))

   (printout t "Input B: ")
   (bind ?B (explode$ (readline)))

   (if (intersectionp ?A ?B) then (printout t " Something ..." crlf)))
CLIPS> (run)
Input A: 1 2 3 4 5
Input B: 7 3 2 1 6
 Something ...
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Input A: 1 2 3
Input B: 4 5 6
CLIPS>
```

Alternately you can use pattern matching to test for an intersection:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS>    
(defrule r       
   =>
   (printout t "Input A: ")
   (bind ?A (explode$ (readline)))
   (assert (A ?A))

   (printout t "Input B: ")
   (bind ?B (explode$ (readline)))
   (assert (B ?B)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule intersect
   (exists (A $? ?v $?)
           (B $? ?v $?))
   =>
   (printout t " Something ..." crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Input A: 1 2 3 4 5
Input B: 7 3 2 1 6
 Something ...
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Input A: 1 2 3
Input B: 4 5 6
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, thank you very much M. Riley.

Comment: In the rule for intersection is there a way to printout the intersected values? because printing ?v throws an error.

Comment: The exists conditional element determines if there is at least one occurrence matching the patterns it contains, so the variable ?v does not have a specific value bound to it outside the scope of the conditional element. Remove the exists conditional element from around the containing patterns and the variable ?v will be in scope in the actions of the rule and you can print its value.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.